# Why are leaves on my plant drying and have white spots?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, leaves, diseases

I have a plant (I don't know what kind of a plant is it) which used to be in the hallway of the building I live in. I didn't really take good care of it and most of the leaves dried up and fell off. A couple of weeks ago I brought it into my apartment where I took better care of it. The leaves started growing again very quickly. But they had white spots on. I didn't bother too much about the white spots until a couple of days ago when the leaves started drying up. The white spots are a discoloration of leaves, not a covering.

Does anyone know why are the leaves getting dry and why do they have white spots on them?

EDIT: There are also some small black dots visible on the leaves now (the dots can be easily removed from the surface), but I couldn't see whether they are bugs or not (not even with a magnifying glass). I have also added a picture of these black dots (the picture at the right).

Here are some pictures:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |